# How to generate global property access expression with the Typescript Compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to generate some typescript code using the [compiler api](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#creating-and-printing-a-typescript-ast). Unfortunately official (or any for that matter) documentation is sparse, and I am now completely stuck on a very simple task:

I want to generate a simple function call like `foo()`. That's all, a simple global function call.

After a long search I have come this far:

```
import ts from 'typescript'

ts.createCall(
    ts.createPropertyAccess(
        *some expression*,
        'foo'
    ),
    undefined, //generics
    [], //parameters
);
```

As far as I understand it I need to pass an expression to `createPropertyAccess` to be the 'owner' of the accessed property (like `foo` in `foo.bar`). However, in this case there is no 'owner' because the function resides in the global scope.

Is there a way to generate such a function call? I tried using `ts.createOmittedExpression`, but that generated the following code:

```
().bar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you can just use `ts.createIdentifier`. There's no property access expression in `foo()`.

```
const statement = ts.createExpressionStatement(
    ts.createCall(ts.createIdentifier("foo"), undefined, undefined)
);
```

By the way, check out my site [ts-ast-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/). It will now show the compiler API code that will create the code in the editor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely overlooked the fact the identifiers are expressions too. Sometimes the AST has so many types/options that I just can't figure out the one I need to use. So far your site has helped a lot with this, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey no problem! I'm glad it was helpful. By the way, check out this feature I just implemented in ts-ast-viewer. It will be very useful for you: https://github.com/dsherret/ts-ast-viewer/issues/40#issuecomment-473751241